# Casting Protobuf Messages to their Extended type

Tags: swift, protocol-buffers

Im learning about protobuf and am playing with [alexeyxo/protobuf-swift](https://github.com/alexeyxo/protobuf-swift).
**Is there a way to cast protobuf Messages into the type they extend?**

proto file:

```
message Command_Login {
    extend SessionCommand {
        optional Command_Login ext = 1001;
    }
    optional string user_name = 1;
    optional string password = 2;
}
```

Here is the `swift`code:

```
let commandContainerBuilder = CommandContainer.Builder()
commandContainerBuilder.sessionCommand.append(commandLogin)
// sessionCommand is an array of SessionCommand (of which Command_Login extends)
```

Error:

`Cannot convert value of type CommandLogin? to expected argument type SessionCommand`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, you've misinterpreted extensions. I say "sorry" because this is probably my fault -- I designed the "extensions" feature, and unfortunately by using the word "extend" I confused a lot of people.

You see, extensions have nothing to do with inheritance. In your example, you are **not** declaring that `Command_Login` is any kind of subclass of `SessionCommand`. This is easier to understand if we shift the declarations around a bit:

```
message Command_Login {
    optional string user_name = 1;
    optional string password = 2;
}

extend SessionCommand {
    optional Command_Login ext = 1001;
}
```

The above is completely valid and exactly equivalent to your code except for one difference: In your version, the extension's name is `Command_Login.ext` (because you declared it nested inside `Command_Login`), but in my version the name is just `ext` (in the global scope). Other than namespacing, they function the same.

What the `extend` clause actually does is declare a new field on `SessionContext`, where the type of that field is `Command_Login`. If you happen to place an `extend` clause inside of a `message` block, this only matters for namespacing purposes, much like declaring static members of a class in C++ or Java.